# Join meshes together without lining up edges

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

A project on mine has been long on ice because I had issues combining a lot of meshes together. I don't have too much experience in Blender as I do in Fusion360.

---

The object in question is a rip from a game, and not all objects have the desired joined meshes.

Here is a short gif of the issue:

[image: Model in blender, mesh problem gif illustration]

The reason I need to combine them, is because the model is supposed to move, and the mesh needs to be joined to prevent having to make the movements stiff.

I know it's possible to manually put holes in the object, have the edges align, and fill the holes making them join, but that is a long process for the amount of separated meshes in this object.

Are there any easy way to "combine" or "join" the selected meshes together?

Any help is appreciated

---

**EDIT**

I uploaded the file to pasteall.org if anyone wants to have a look at it: https://pasteall.org/blend/a5632814da22431d9c612c3351ef8d03

Comment: CTRL + J is to join

Comment: you can try a boolean: Select the belt then Face > Intersect (Boolean) and in the Operator box choose Union, and see what it gives?

Comment: @Emir `CTRL + J` doesn't seem to do anything. In edit mode, nothing happends when I do the shortcut, in object mode I get this error: `No mesh data to join`

Comment: please share the belt so that we can give a try: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I updated the question and provided the link to the blend file

Answer (score 0):

You could try to boolean the pins to the belt but the result will be a bit messy. Another way would be to separate each pin (<kbd>L</kbd> to select, <kbd>P</kbd> to separate, you can also try to separate 4 pins together as one object), then select several of them, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the belt, switch to *Edit* mode, select 3 vertices of the belt and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to parent to these empty. Now the pins are attached to the belt and will follow it:

[image]